# How do I do /tell using scoreboards

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to use the `/tell` command, but only tell people with a certain scoreboard value. How do I do that? I understand that in older versions it used to look like this:

```
/tell @a[score_scoreboard=1,score_scoreboard_min=1,score_anotherscoreboard=3,score_anotherscoreboard_min=3]]
```

However, I want to use this command in 1.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just like all scoreboard target selectors:

```
/tell @a[scores={scoreboard_name=1..}] Hi!
```

The problem you have is probably that you don't have access to "OP" commands, therefore you can't use target selector arguments like `scores`.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
/execute as @a if score @s <objective> matches <criteria> run /tell @s <blah blah blah>
```

With the tell command, this will make it look like the player is talking to themselves. I would prefer tellraw.